# iOS user default name format issue

Tags: ios

Using the following method i get the right order instantly on iOS 5 but the order not changing on iOS 6 & 7 after switching it in the settings, nor after restarting application (after closing settings).

```
BOOL firstNameFirst = NO;

if (IOS_VERSION>=7) {
    firstNameFirst = (ABPersonGetCompositeNameFormatForRecord(NULL)==kABPersonCompositeNameFormatFirstNameFirst);
}else{
    firstNameFirst = (ABPersonGetCompositeNameFormat() == kABPersonCompositeNameFormatFirstNameFirst);
}
```

What am i missing?

EDIT:
This bool supposed to store the **user default** order, so i can order the first and last name strings and show them to the user in the way he set it in the iPhone settings.

EDIT2: the `IOS_VERSION` macro works perfectly, i checked them using breakpoint, but whatever the *Settings / Mail, Contacts, Calendar / Contacts / Display Order* settings is, i always get `YES` for `firstNameFirst`'s value

Comment: How do you declare `IOS_VERSION` ?

Comment: `#define IOS_VERSION [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue]`
in a `Common.h` with my other macros included in the prefix header.

Comment: I would suggest that you rewire your marco to use the example given bij apple, `if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) ` this is from the [iOS 7 UI Transition Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/SupportingEarlieriOS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH14-SW1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hope to be helpful to you.

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);

BOOL firstNameFirst = NO;

if (IOS_VERSION>=7) {
    firstNameFirst = (ABPersonGetCompositeNameFormatForRecord(NULL)==kABPersonCompositeNameFormatFirstNameFirst);
}else{
    firstNameFirst = (ABPersonGetCompositeNameFormat() == kABPersonCompositeNameFormatFirstNameFirst);
}

if(addressBook != NULL) {
    CFRelease(addressBook);
}
```

Comment: Instant changes, now everything works as i wanted, Many thanks!

Comment: won't the line `ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);` create a memory leak?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) 
{

    // Load resources for iOS 6.1 or earlier

} else 
{

    // Load resources for iOS 7 or later

}
```

do like this. 
reference taken from this.

[This Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TransitionGuide/SupportingEarlieriOS.html)

Comment: While your and @rckoenes suggestion is right, it is not a solution to my problem, also makes using the macro a little bit complicated than before.